# C Structure Initialization and Segmentation Fault

Tags: c

I have initialized a Structure through a Pointer and I have tried to get values using Pointer too. I am getting Segmentation Fault. Any Clue on it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void){
    struct MemData{
        char* FileName;
        int LastByteLength;
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        char Data[ 512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    struct MemData* M;
    M->FileName=(char*)"xaa";
    M->LastByteLength=0;
    M->ReadPointer=-1;
    M->WritePointer=-1;
    printf("\n%s", M->FileName);
    printf("\n%d", M->LastByteLength);
    printf("\n%d", M->ReadPointer);
    printf("\n%d", M->WritePointer);

}
```

Comment: `struct MemData* M;` declares a pointer, but you never initialized it. `M` points nowhere.

Comment: Maybe you want : `struct MemData M;` (without the `*`) and change all `M->` to `M.`. Read the chapter dealing with structs and the one dealing with pointers in your C text book.

Comment: You forgot to initialize your pointer `M`, so of course you're getting a segmentation fault.  What did you expect it to point to?  It's undefined behavior.

Comment: Not related to your question, 512kib = 512*1024, which is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate M.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void){
  struct MemData{
     char* FileName;
     int LastByteLength;
     int ReadPointer;
     int WritePointer;
     char Data[ 512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
  };
  struct MemData* M;
  M = malloc(sizeof(*M));
  M->FileName="xaa";
  M->LastByteLength=0;
  M->ReadPointer=-1;
  M->WritePointer=-1;
  printf("\n%s", M->FileName);
  printf("\n%d", M->LastByteLength);
  printf("\n%d", M->ReadPointer);
  printf("\n%d", M->WritePointer);
  free(M);
}
```

Try the above code, it should works.

As [Broman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699433/broman) suggested in comments I edited the answer removing the unnecessary "(char*)" cast as string literal already has the type char*

Comment: [Don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/6699433)

Comment: Also, instead of `sizeof(struct MemData)`, use `sizeof (*M)`

Comment: Reason: What happens if you want to rename `MemData` or change the code to use another struct? Then you need to change the code on several places.

Comment: This allocates memory and points `M` to that memory. It doesn't allocate `M` (which is already allocated automatically)

Comment: Broman thanks for the good hints, I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: You should also remove the `(char*)` cast. It's completely unnecessary. A string literal already has the type `char*`. (Well, not really but it's close enough)

Comment: I know OP wrote like that, but why not fix what can be fixed? You could also improve your answer by a short note about why you removed the casts.